# Update the appended child on props change by using useRef

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
const A= (props) => {

  const {category,screen} = props

  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(()=>{
    const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "xyz.js"
      script.async = true;
      script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({"width": 1100,
      "height": 512,
      "market": category
})
      ref.current.appendChild(script)
      return () => {ref.current.removeChild(script);} // not working
  },[category])

    return (
<div className="tradingview-widget-container" ref={ref}>
  <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
 
</div>
    )
}

export default A
```

I have created this component so that whenever the category is changed then the appended child will be replaced with a script having the new "market" value as passed from props(category)

It is working fine but the removing of the child is not working and without using this it keeps on adding the scripts again and again which makes the component appearing multiple times and not updating itself

How can i update this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all never use vanilla js `createElement` or jquery inside react . Second of all the useEffect hook has two parts :

```
useEffect(()=>{
   
   // This part will run on component mount
   console.log("Component did mount")
   return  () => {
   
   // This part will run on component unmount 
   console.log("Component did unmount")
   }
} , [state] )
```

You don't need to include the return callback function always but only when you need to do something on component unmount .

In react js you can have multiple useEffects . So you may want to use another useEffect for the other condition which is the [category] .

Comment: ok u mean create two useEffects...one for adding the script with category dependency and another for removing it without any dependency

Comment: @tanmay yes and I appreciate If you mark this an answer for your question If it helped you at all

Comment: in the second useEffect its saying Script is not defined because we created the script in the first one

Comment: @tanmay Just like I said before using javascript createElement is not supported in react js so you may want to change that logic into react way of doing that . If not you have to have duplicate code in both useEffects .